# storing a bunch of dates on a separate table, but have trouble fetching it properly

Tags: php, mysql

I have some tasks that I have to store in my database. And each task has an array of dates in which the tasks were completed. I've learn that it is better to not use a array (serialize) to store dates, but instead make another table. So I did:

taskTable contains columns: `taskID`, `userid`, `description`, `name`

task_days contains columns: `taskID`, `day`

But Im having trouble with php, 
usually I can easily send my data to client with:

```
        function getTasks(){

            $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
            $userid = $app->request->params('userid');

            $db = getDB();
            $result = $db->prepare("Select * From taskTable where userid = ?");
            $result->execute(array($userid));
            $result->setFetchmode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);



            echo json_encode($result->fetchAll());
        }
```

I encode it, then client can easily read it as an array of JSON. But now with two tables, I'm not sure how to do it efficiently. I know I can get the required information with this query:

`Select * from taskTable as t, task_days as d where t.taskID = d.taskID`

But how do I make it so the days will be in an array associated with the correct task.

Do I first `Select * From taskTable where userid = $userid`, then for each task, I will do a query on table task_days? that seems extremely inefficient though.

So I want something like the following:

```
[
{taskid: 123, userid: 1, description: "do task", name: "tony", day:[1998-01-02, 1998-02-03]},
{taskid: 124, userid: 2, description: "do task2", name: "Ann", day:[2016-01-02, 2016-02-03, 2016-01-01]},
...
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of approaches.

1) One approach, as you already outline, is to run a query that returns the the columns from just `taskTable`. And for each row returned, run another query to get the associated rows from `task_days`. And you are right, that's usually not the most efficient approach. But for a reasonably small number of rows, performance should be reasonable as long as appropriate indexes are available.)

---

2) Another approach, assuming `taskid` is the primary key of `taskTable` is to perform a join, and use a "GROUP BY" to collapse the rows. The "GROUP_CONCAT" aggregate function can convert the multiple values of `day` from the `task_days` table into a single string. For example:

```
 SELECT t.taskid
      , t.userid
      , t.description
      , t.name
      , GROUP_CONCAT(d.day ORDER BY d.day) AS `day`
   FROM taskTable t
   LEFT
   JOIN task_days d 
     ON d.taskid = t.taskid 
  GROUP BY t.taskid
  ORDER BY t.taskid
```

This would return the `day` as a string, not an array. If you need an array, your code would need to do that. (As a convenient way to do that, the PHP explode function might be suitable.)

NOTE:  the length of the string returned by GROUP_CONCAT is limited by `group_concat_max_len` variable, and also by `max_allowed_packet`.

---

3) Another way to approach this is to perform a join operation, and pull back the "duplicated" task information, ordered by `taskid` and `day`

```
 SELECT t.taskid
      , t.userid
      , t.description
      , t.name
      , d.day
   FROM taskTable t
   LEFT
   JOIN task_days d 
     ON d.taskid = t.taskid 
  ORDER BY t.taskid, d.day
```

That would get a result set like this:

```
   taskid  userid  description  name   day
   ------  ------  -----------  -----  ----------
      123       1  do task      tony   1998-01-02
      123       1  do task      tony   1998-02-03
      124       2  do task2     Ann    2016-01-02
      124       2  do task2     Ann    2016-02-03
      124       2  do task2     Ann    2016-01-01
```

Then your code would need to do some rudimentary "control break" processing. Basically, compare the taskid of the current row to the taskid from the previous row. If they match, you are processing just a new `day` value for the same task.

If the taskid of the current row is different than the taskid from the previous row, then you are starting a new task.

Your code would effectively be ignoring the duplicated rows from `taskTable`, basically squinting at the result set and seeing it like this:

```
   taskid  userid  description  name   day
   ------  ------  -----------  -----  ----------
 -    123       1  do task      tony   1998-01-02
 +                                     1998-02-03
 -    124       2  do task2     Ann    2016-01-02
 +                                     2016-02-03
 +                                     2016-01-01
```

---

**FOLLOWUP**

The second option is closest to your original implementation, a comma separated list of values as a string, in a character column.

As far as storing a comma separated list, that's a SQL anti-pattern, and it's usually best avoided it. Multi-valued attributes can be stored in a separate table, like you have done.

The exception would be if you never, *ever* need the database to see the values in the list as separate values.

If you are storing that "list of dates" as if it were an image, for example like the contents of a jpeg... if you *always* store the entire value into the column, and *always* extract the contents of the column as a single value... if *never* need to search for an individual date, or add a date to an existing list, or remove a date from a list... and if you *never* need the database to enforce any constraints on the values, or do any validation of the contents...

If all of those conditions are satisfied, only then might it make sense to store a comma separated list as a single column.

---

My personal preference, if the implementation is targeted only to MySQL, would be the second option... using `GROUP_CONCAT`. If the length of the string generated by the `GROUP_CONCAT` *exceeds* `group_concat_max_len`, the string will be truncated, with no warning or error. (I believe that's a limitation in bytes, and not characters.)

The safest coding practice would be to do perform a query:

```
 SELECT @@session.group_concat_max_len
```

save the value returned by that. Then, for the values returned from the `GROUP_CONCAT` expression, compare the length (in bytes) to the saved value, to see if truncation has occurred. (If the length of the returned string is *less* than the value of `group_concat_max_len`, then you can be pretty confident that truncation has not occurred.)  It's also possible to override the current value of the variable (before you run the statement containing `GROUP_CONCAT`, with a separate `SET` statement. Something like this:

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 131072 ;
```

(Just be careful not to exceed `max_allowed_packet`.)

Comment: Thanks for listing out all my options. So far I like the second one, but this make me question what I've read. In my case then isn't it better to serialize and store all days into an array instead of creating this new table, since I wont be using sql function such as count(*) or avg. I just want to get the days for each task everytime I call GET or when I POST. With something like the second option each time I connect to database I have to parse the string into an array or when I post I have to parse a array into a string. Or is this more efficient? Thanks again for the detailed explanation